# Auth0 redirects me to the login page when I add a logout button to an Angular component

Tags: angular, debugging, auth0, logout

I'm fairly new to auth0. I have an Angular application with several pages that requires authentication. At the moment the user arrives on the home page and is then redirected to an auth0 authentication page to log in. Once the connection is successful, the user is redirected to a /app page.
All this works well. However, as soon as I add a button that calls the auth0 logout() function in this app page, the behaviour changes. This time, once the user has logged in, they are redirected to the /app page and then immediately afterwards to the home page. It's as if the user is immediately logged out. However, it seems that the user is not logged out, judging by the isAuthenticated$ variables in auth0.

I'd like the disconnect button to no longer cause this problem.
At first I thought that the user was logged out directly and that the two pages, login and app, didn't share the same auth0 session. However, they do use the same service, which is declared separately, and as I said, it seems that the user isn't logged out. This would explain the redirection to the start page but not the fact that the user still seems to be logged in. I'd therefore like to set up an auth0 logout logic on my auth0 app page that doesn't create a bug.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: make sure you add `type="button"` on your `<button>` element, the default type is submit which will cause the page to reload, and could be causing your issue

Comment: Thank you for you answer, yes indeed I have this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the `returnTo` parameter? Here's what I'm using in one of my examples:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { AsyncPipe, DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-home',
  imports: [AsyncPipe],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.css'
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document) {
  }

  login(): void {
    this.auth.loginWithRedirect();
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.auth.logout({
      logoutParams: {
        returnTo: this.doc.location.origin
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I do have something similar in my code.

The problem really appears when, in my component where I want the disconnection to take place, I add everything auth0 needs. In other words, I import my auth0 service and put it in the constructor where I also define the logout function from this service.

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose that your component Login.
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="loginStatus">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" *ngIf="loginStatus">Aboutus</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" *ngIf="loginStatus">ContactUS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="!loginStatus 
(click)="login()">
    Login
  </button>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" *ngIf="loginStatus" (click)="logout()">
       Logout
     </button>
     </li>
```

```
Your typeScript File
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { CartserviceService } from '../cartservice.service';   
@Component({
     selector: 'app-login',
     templateUrl: './login.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
 })
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(public cS: CartserviceService, public aS: AuthService) {}
   cartCount;
   loginStatus;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cS.cartCount.subscribe((c) => {
      this.cartCount = c;
    });
    this.aS.isLoggedIn.subscribe((status) => {
      this.loginStatus = status;
    });
  }
  login() {
        if(this.loginForm.valid){
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }else{
          console.log("user id and password not valid");
        }
}

logout(){
 this.router.navigate(['login']); Here you can redirect as per requirement
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit Rai, thank you for your reply. 
In fact I have a login button on the home page and the logout button is on another page (a /app page). So I can't do it the way you specified where everything is located in a navbar. So when the user logs in he starts from the home page, then he is directed to the auth0 authentication page and if this is successful the user is redirected to the app page. But when I create the logout button in the app page, there's then an immediate redirect to the home page even though the user still seems to be logged in. So that's my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ari suppose that you have one component name login.
 you add here login button like this  
 <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary" (click)=loginForm()>Login</button>
 after login you redirect to other page like dashboard or home.
An other component here like Home and Dashboard.
simply add the this code (home or Dashboard component) for where are you redirect. 
<p><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></p>
Note: routerLink modify as your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yes the thing is I use auth0. The logic of disconnection is correct, there must be something else...